# Intuitive interpretation of the Fourier transform of the derivatives of a function

Tags: fourier-analysis, intuition

Let $f$ be a smooth function, $f(t)\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$, and $F$ be its Fourier transform $$F(\omega):=\mathcal F f\,(\omega)\,=\,\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm e^{-\mathrm i\omega t}f(t)\mathrm{d}t.$$
Then it is easy to check (e.g. using integration by parts) that for the nth derivative $f^{(n)}(t)$, we have
$$\mathcal F f^{(n)}\,(\omega)\,=\,(\mathrm i\omega)^n\,F(\omega).$$

While it is straight forward to do this calculations, I'm having a hard time understanding what is happening intuitively. The Fourier transform denotes the contribution of each frequency appearing in the underlying function. How can I interpret the above result in a similar manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential function $e^{zt}$ is the eigenfunction of the differentiation operator, with eigenvalue $z$. The Fourier Transform essentially expresses a function as a linear combination of $e^{i\omega t}$ basis functions, so differentiating this linear combination is simply multiplication by the eigenvalue $i\omega$. This is analogous to applying a linear operator to a linear combination of basis vectors - the result is entirely determined by the operator's mapping of the basis vectors.

Comment: Nice answer that already helped getting an intuition. What I still want to understand is why for instance the Fourier transform of the second derivative (curvature) is minus the squared frequency times the original Fourier transform. It seems like they are the same (forgetting about the sign), but with the $omega^2$ factor amplifying high frequency components.

Comment: Well, perhaps think about a single sinusoid. When you take the derivative of that, you get another sinusoid scaled by a factor equal to the frequency. This makes sense: when you increase the frequency of a wave, you tangent lines becomes steeper, because you decrease the period of time over which the function changes. You have to "get to the same point" in a shorter period of time. As I mentioned before, the Fourier Transform expresses a function as a linear combination of sinusoids, so the $\omega$ scaling factor is simply each component being scaled by it's relevant frequency.

Comment: Another thing to remember is that not every result can be grasped in an intuitive sense. Sometimes surprising things just fall out of the math. A lot of Fourier results seem that way to me at least, the formula for Fourier series coefficients for example. I understand the derivation, but *why* those results happen to true escapes me completely. Likewise for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm e^{-x^{2}}\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt\pi$. It's easy enough to get this result, but why is it true?